# Convert VirtualBox dynamic VDI disk image to static, fixed VDI

Tags: virtualbox, vdi

I've originally created my VDI to auto-expand to 20GB of virtual capacity.

For performance reasons, I would like to convert them to linear, that is, to have a single, non-sparse, 20GB file sitting on the disk, instead of the dynamically expanding, prone to fragmentation image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [vboxmanage clonehd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi):

```
vboxmanage clonehd olddisk.vdi newdisk.vdi --variant fixed
```